# In this super easy program written in C won't let me read a variable of type "char"?

Tags: c, char, printf, scanf

This *easy* code in C won't work, and I don't get it why. If I read only "n", or only "ch" separately, it works, otherwise if I try to read them both, it won't let me read "ch". What happens and how could I make it work?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    char ch;

    printf("n=");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("ch="); //when i press Build and Run it won't let me read "ch"??? why?
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: by 'wont let you' you mean it is reading a value you don't expect such as the newline ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read in a number using `%d`, a newline is left in the input buffer.  When you then read a character with `%c`, it reads that newline immediately so you don't get prompted for more input.

Unlike the `%d` format specifier, which discards any leading whitespace, the `%c` format specifier does not.

Add a leading space before `%c` to consume any leftover whitespace:

```
scanf(" %c",&ch);
```

Comment: it's working now, thanks a lot!

Comment: @meiznub Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.